# Backbone: Call an extended view's overridden render() function

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js, overriding

I have a `WorkoutExerciseRowView` which extends `ExerciseRowView`. The render functions are extremely similar, except the `WorkoutExerciseRowView` must add a few parameters to `ExerciseRowView`'s render. How can I call `ExerciseRowView`'s render function inside `WorkoutExerciseRowView`'s render function?

```
var WorkoutExerciseRowView = ExerciseRowView.extend( {      
    render : function() {
        //return this.constructor.render({ // doesn't work
        return this.render({ // doesn't work
            workoutExercise : this.model,
            exercise : this.model.get("exercise"),
            workoutSection : this.model.get("section"),
            isEditable : true,
            number : this.number,
            WorkoutExercise : WorkoutExercise,
            WorkoutSection : WorkoutSection
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var WorkoutExerciseRowView = ExerciseRowView.extend( {      
    render : function() {
        return ExerciseRowView.prototype.render.call(this,{
            workoutExercise : this.model,
            exercise : this.model.get("exercise"),
            workoutSection : this.model.get("section"),
            isEditable : true,
            number : this.number,
            WorkoutExercise : WorkoutExercise,
            WorkoutSection : WorkoutSection
        });
    }
});
```

From Backbone's documentation here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend

> Brief aside on super: JavaScript does not provide a simple way to call
>   super — the function of the same name defined higher on the prototype
>   chain. If you override a core function like set, or save, and you want
>   to invoke the parent object's implementation, you'll have to
>   explicitly call it, along these lines:

`Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);`

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use

```
ExerciseRowView.prototype.render.call(this)
```

This will call the render function from ExerciseRowView with the scope set to this (current model)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.constructor.__super__.render.call(this,{});
```

Comment: According to posts on github, __super__ shouldn't be used.